# Loading arguments from console

Tags: command-line, console, command-line-arguments, fibonacci, logramm

I've written a console script, with a simple implementation of the Fibonacci recursive algorithm.

However, I searched in the docs and still cannot find how to get a number param from the command line. How is that possible?

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/lgm -l

import core.number;

fibo(x) =>
{
    x<=1 :==> 1;
    ==> fibo(x-1)+fibo(x-2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*@G.Stevens is correct.*

Commands line arguments can be accessed via the global `__Args` variable.

So, in your case, if you need the first argument, all you have to do is `__Args[0]`.

And since you want is as number :

```
__Args[0].fromBase(10)
```

from `core.number` (which you're already importing anyway...)

Answer (score 5):

Command line arguments are stored in the `__Args` variable.

So, you can use them pretty much like any normal array.